# Create a custom object record when a user self register's through community

Tags: community, process-builder

I am actually trying to figure out a way wherein when a user self register's to a community(lightning) i want a custom object record to be created , i assume this can be done through process builder , but what is the condition that i should check whether or not to see if the contact/user record is created through self-registration.

Answer (score 0):

Community `Contact` records have a reference to the `User` that is created when the self-registration is done; the field's API name is probably `UserId`. So you could check for when that `Contact.UserId` field is modified.

An alternative is to modify the registration logic - see e.g. [Customize the Community Self-Registration Process with Apex](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_self_reg_apex.htm&type=5).

Comment: i don't want to customize the self-registration process , what i am actually looking for is a condition which says if a community user is created through self-registration , if yes then create a custom object record.

Comment: @Harry_G The change event is when the `Contact.UserId` field is modified. If you just want to check is a `User` is a community user you could query if there is a child `Contact`.